# Must I save a json file to re-construct a Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

- [How to Save and Load Your Keras Deep Learning Model](https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models)

In the above article, they are creating both JSON and HDF5 files,

```
    # serialize model to JSON
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    # serialize weights to HDF5
    model.save_weights("model.h5")
    print("Saved model to disk")
```

and, later... they are reloading JSON and HDF5 and combining them to create the model:

```
    # load json and create model
    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
    print("Loaded model from disk")
```

Must I save a JSON model along with HDF5 to re-construct a Keras model?

Can I save the model only in HDF5 format and reload it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked is pretty old and does not use the best practices.

You can save the whole model (including architecture, weights, and even optimizer state) into a single HDF5 file using `model.save('something.h5')`, and then load it using

```
model = keras.models.load_model('something.h5')
```

This has been standard for many years in Keras. There is no need to use JSON files to store the architecture.